# reveal js modal doesn't work with latest jQuery release

Tags: jquery, html, reveal.js

So, this now works... with the addition of the migrate file. yay for more HTTP requests...

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

<s>So after review, the reveal.js modal only works with jQuery 1.6 down to 1.4, is there any way to make it work with the more recent versions of jQuery? Is there anything specific that is preventing it from working?</s>

So the simple plugin reveal.js modal used by Zurb is awesome, and I've used it in the past. However, I can't seem to get it to operate on the current implementation, it just doesn't fire when you click on any of the links to open the modal. I've got it working on various other sites, so I'm beginning to think it is a jquery overlap somewhere. I'm using the data- method to fire but also have tried the programmatic method as well to no avail.

Link to the site: [url removed] (no server side scripting has been applied yet)

First and most obvious question, is it compatible with jQuery 2.0.0?

Second question, I'm using modernizr, tabify, and selectivizr. Are there any known issues or conflicts with these three plugins and reveal.js that would prevent it from loading properly?

I've gone through the styles and haven't been able to discern any conflicts yet, but still don't know javascript well enough to troubleshoot that aspect of things. So anyone with some spare time that can lend a hand on this I'd appreciate greatly. I apologize ahead of time for not putting up a fiddle, but without knowing the issue that may be difficult and too cumbersome for a fiddle.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: There was only an error with modernizr,
Those being: "document.body doesn't exist. Modernizr hyphens test needs it. modernizr.min.js:4" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"

I'll post a fiddle in the morning and see if I can't make sense of what exactly it is, I haven't had time to dig too deep into it the last two days. But it's working, just with a later version. It works  up to 1.8.3, didn't work in 1.9.1 or 2.0.0, but it could be associated with other variables I'm not looking at.

Comment: Updated question with solution.

Comment: Put the solution as an answer and accept it, makes more sense for everyone else then.

Comment: You're absolutely correct

Comment: Revel has been rolled into the revolution frame work, so updates to the stand alone version won't be coming.    From https://github.com/zurb/reveal `Note: This version of Reveal has been deprecated and will no longer be developed or supported. For the most recent code, check out the responsive version of Reveal included in Foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/, our rapid prototyping and production framework.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by using a version older than 1.8.3 of jquery or adding the migrate file provided by the jquery camp on versions higher.

> jQuery Migrate plugin
>   We have created the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify the transition from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later. Use the uncompressed development version to diagnose compatiblity issues, it will generate warnings on the console that you can use to identify and fix problems. Use the compressed production version to simply fix compatibility issues without generating console warnings.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I recently ran into this as well.  You don't have to upload any migrate js files. You can make an easy update to the jquery.reveal.js file instead.

the reveal script uses `.live()` to find the appropriate `<a>` tags. This is removed in newer version of jquery, so replace them with `.on` instead.

In jquery.reveal.js, change

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on( "click", "a[data-reveal-id]", function(e) {
```